# CMIC_VALID_SEE_FLAGS / SEE_VALID_CMIC_FLAGS in MinGW Windows headers - what's the deal with these?

Tags: winapi, mingw

In the MinGW Windows API bindings, file shlobj.h, there is this line:

```
#define CMIC_VALID_SEE_FLAGS   SEE_VALID_CMIC_FLAGS
```

Nowhere in the headers is SEE_VALID_CMIC_FLAGS defined.  A search on MSDN reveals nothing.

What is the purpose of this line?

Answer (score 0):

`SEE_` prefix refers to flags in the [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784) (apparently from
[`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154) where it's used).

`CMIC_` prefix is for flags in the [`CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773215) (used by [`IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096)).

If you check their definition, you'll see that they're basically mirroring each other. My guess is that `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand` just copies the flags to a `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure and invokes `ShellExecuteEx`.

The value of `CMIC_VALID_SEE_FLAGS`/`SEE_VALID_CMIC_FLAGS` is not defined in any of the current Win32 headers, but I imagine it was present in some old SDK at the time MinGW authors were making their own headers. From the name, it seems to the a set of flags which are valid in *both* `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` and `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`. My guess is that it's used internally in the implementation of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand` similar to this:

```
if ( pici->fMask & ~CMIC_VALID_SEE_FLAGS )
{
   // unsupported flags present. do some extra work
}
else
{
   // we can use it as-is
   SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei;
   sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
   sei.fMask = pici->fMask;
   // ... etc
   ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
}
```

In short, do not bother with this define. Just use the documented flags from MSDN.